# jQuery/JavaScript equivalent of each() for a single element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, each

Can someone tell me how to update the following code to just get the first item that's returned in an object (data)? I know using each() for just one item isn't very efficient and would like to improve it.

```
$(data).each(function(num, entry){
    if ( num > 1 ) return false;
});
```

Here's an example of what `data` is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "My post",
        "permalink":"http:\/\/site.com\/page.html\/",
        "date":" 2011-05-10 
    }
]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update 2:**

As `data` is just an array (I assume the JSON is already parsed (if not you can use `jQuery.parseJSON` or `JSON.parse`)), you can get the first element with simple array access:

```
var first = data[0];
```

[Read more about arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

---

*Old answer:*

Try

```
$(data).first()      // returns jQuery object
// or
$(data).eq(0)        // returns jQuery object
// or 
$(data).get(0)       // returns DOM object
// or
$(data)[0]           // returns DOM object
```

depending on the data you have and what you want to do.

**Update:**

If `data` is actually a JavaScript object, then there is no need to pass it to jQuery (jQuery is mostly for working with the DOM).

Just loop over it with

```
for(var prop in data) {

}
```

But you cannot get the "first" property because they are unordered.

If it is an array, just use `data[0]`.

To help you more, you should post what `data` is.

Comment: Thanks! Before, I was doing something like entry.title, entry.image, etc. to define properties from the JSON data. How would I do this now using one of your methods?

Comment: $(data).first() returns a jQuery object with a single element, so you can call it ``var entry = $(data).first();`` and then ``entry.title`` will return the same as your original ``each``.

Comment: @Cofey: If it is an object, then you should do it totally differently. Please see my update and post what exactly `data` is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do [this](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
$(data).get(0); //same as $(data)[0]
```