# equivalent of each for json call

Tags: jquery, json, each

I normally make a JSON call like this:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){

   var productsHtml = '';

   $.each(json.products, function(index, product){
```

I then can build my HTMl like so:

```
productsHtml = '<div>'+ product.name +'</div>';
```

I was wondering how to do this when you just have one product to loop. Normally you need to put 'data' in front of an element. Like so:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){

       var productsHtml = '<div>'+ data.product.name +'</div>';
```

The problem is that I need to put 'data' in front of product.name. Is there a way where I don't need to use 'data' in front of the product name and just can type 'product.name'?

Don't ask me why, I am just wondering. I found a post that has the same question but I can't figure out how to deal with that wit the example above!

[jQuery/JavaScript equivalent of each() for a single element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955892/jquery-javascript-equivalent-of-each-for-a-single-element)

Comment: `var product = data.product`?

Comment: The product name is in the variable called `data` so yes, you need to use it at some point. If for some reason you really want you can do `var product = data.product;` to get the same thing as in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `with` **but this is not a recommanded practice**.

Check why here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with#Description

```
with(data){
    var productsHtml = '<div>'+product.name +'</div>';
}
```